# pathlib path.glob iterating results with for loop question

Tags: python, path, generator, pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

path=Path(PureWindowsPath('c:/test'))
print(file for file in path.glob('*.*'))
print("\n")
for file in path.glob('*.*'):print(file)
```

I am a noob learning python, i cannot understand the difference between both for loops and result. I get generator object in one and file names in the other.

result is:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000002D8446B3970>


c:\test\Changes.xlsx
c:\test\North Accounts V1.1.xlsx
c:\test\North Customer Contact Details.xlsx
c:\test\Py_Test.xlsx
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.glob` is an iterable and your expression `file for file in path.glob(..)` makes an iterable out of an iterable. This is unnecessary but also gives the wrong result since when you print it you get the string representation of the *iterable* (which is this weird number) and not of the elements it iterates over.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that this syntax:
`(x for x in [1, 2, 3])` creates a generator object.

In contrast this one:
`[x for x in [1, 2, 3]]`

creates a list.

When you directly print a generator, you are not seeing its content. You can do this instead:

`print([file for file in path.glob('*.*')])`

or

`print(list(file for file in path.glob('*.*')))`

The `list` statement does nothing more but consume an iterable (and a generator is iterable) and returns the result as a list.

Comment: Thanks! i got it now.

Comment: Oh, I did a copy&paste-error there. `print(list(path.glob("*")))` is of course enough. No need to `file for file` inside again - because this is basically what `list` does :)